# RelativePanel PointerPressed Event Won't be fired in UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

what I have tries is?

XAML Code:

```
<Canvas x:Name="grid" Width="500" Height="500">
     <RelativePanel PointerPressed="RelativePanel_PointerPressed" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" Background="Green" Height="100">
        <RichEditBox x:Name="box" Width="100" Height="32" ></RichEditBox>
        <Rectangle RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWith="box" Width="100" Height="10" Fill="Blue" Margin="0 15 0 20"></Rectangle>
    </RelativePanel>
</Canvas>
```

C# Code:

```
   private void RelativePanel_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     Debug.WriteLine("Hello");
   }
```

RichEditBox and rectangle are children of RelativePanel.

When I click over the rectangle ,the pointerPressed evnt of RelativePanel has been fired correctly.

But,when I click on RichEditBox,the event won't be fired.I want to fire the event where ever,i click inside the relative Panel.How to Achieve this?

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If it is not solved, please feel free to contact us.

Comment: yeah.Its Solved.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But,when I click on RichEditBox,the event won't be fired.I want to fire the event where ever,i click inside the relative Panel.How to Achieve this?

You can use the [AddHandler event handing technique](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview#registering-handlers-for-already-handled-routed-events) to specify that you want the `PointerPressed` event handler to be invoked even if the event is marked handled with the third argument set as `true`, like this:

```
box.AddHandler(RichEditBox.PointerReleasedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(RelativePanel_PointerPressed), true);
```

However, you maybe also note that the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.addhandler?view=winrt-19041) says “Do not routinely ask to rehandle a routed event, because it interferes with the intended design of the Windows Runtime event system for control compositing.”

In addition to the above method, we can also use `PointerCaptureLost` event which can be invoked when you click the `RichEditBox` control to replace `PointerPressed` event. For example:

```
<Canvas x:Name="grid" Width="500" Height="500">
    <RelativePanel PointerPressed="RelativePanel_PointerPressed"
                   Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" Background="Green" Height="100">
        <RichEditBox x:Name="box" Width="100" Height="32" PointerCaptureLost="RelativePanel_PointerCaptureLost"/>
        <Rectangle RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWith="box"
                   Width="100" Height="10" Fill="Blue" Margin="0 15 0 20"/>
    </RelativePanel>
</Canvas>
```